# A job interview "with" or "at"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I'm wondering if you could tell me which sentence sounds more natural.

> I'm going to have a job interview with a clothing company today.
>
> I'm going to have a job interview at a clothing company today.

Thank you!

Comment: Either of these prepositions can be used to mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are syntactically correct, and I've heard both. However, there can be a slight amount of nuance when using *with* versus *at*. This is mostly due to cooperation and how much you feel like you're "on the same team" as the company. Just as you work *with* your colleagues, you can interview *with* a company. Depending on the magnitude of the job, saying that you're interviewing with a recognizable company by name might convey more importance than *at*.

- *I'm interviewing with Google*: Implies that you're working to get a job at Google, a big company. It's identifiable and carries a sort of affection, as if you're already *with* them. I've heard this used primarily in the context of *starting a long career* or being at a *very respectable or recognizable company*.
- *I'm interviewing at McDonald's*: Implies that you see yourself working *at* the location, but not that you necessarily are close to the company. I've heard this more common when referring to jobs that aren't the end goal in a person's life. These jobs are usually "just a job" and a way to earn a paycheck. A stepping stone, not a final resting point.

In your example, you said "a clothing company," which, intentionally or not, removes some of the closeness in your context. If you were saying this verbatim, I would go with *at* (*I'm going to have a job interview at a clothing company today*) because you haven't given the name of the company directly. It doesn't give the closeness that *with* gives, but you've already distanced yourself slightly from the company by not giving its proper name.

I've also heard *at* used more in the context of a failed or disliked interview in past tense. For example:

- *I interviewed at Google, and I didn't make it past the second interview.*
- *I interviewed at McDonald's, but the conditions didn't really give me the impression that I should work there.*

Since the job wasn't attained, the implied closeness isn't needed. Many people want to distance themselves from unsuccessful attempts or careers that didn't speak to them.

---

All of this being said, however, I'd like to reiterate: **both are technically correct and commonly heard**. However, if you're trying to convey a tiny bit more information, you can do so by intentionally adding distance or removing it.

Answer (score 0):

## The first one

IMO `with` flows better, and I don't think it implies the clothing company is taking the interview alongside you.

Answer (score 0):

*With X* would be a person or company.

*At X* would be a place.

*At X* can also be used when X is a company, since many companies have offices, buildings, or campuses -- things that are places.

*At X* would never be a person, though.

*At X* also means the focus is more on *where* you are having the interview as opposed to *who* you are interviewing with.  Since larger companies tend to have a more impersonal interview process where you might be waiting in a room, having to take significant time to park, etc. - the focus would be more on the place than your actual interviewer - thus *at X* could carry the implicaton you are interviewing with a large business or firm.